# Where can I find a good perl script for a cronjob that backs up all files in a specific folder on my webspace?

Tags: ftp, backups, automation, cron

I want to automate backups on my webspace. My provider allows for cronjobs to be executed once a day. I have already implemented a cronjob that backs up my database with mySQLdumper, using a perl script. Now I want to use a script that backs up all my files in a specific folder (e.g. /folder/), zips them and moves them to /backups/

Is there a way to do so? If yes, could you recommend a good perl script template that lets me easily modify it so I can use it the way I want? Ideally, it would also have the feature to exclude certain file types, like jpg, gif and png.

Comment: Does it have to be a perl script? A shell script calling gzip would work just fine too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create backsups by simply copying files from one folder to another try rsyncbackup which is a perlscript that does easy backups with rsync

http://code.google.com/p/rsync-backup/

You can set a cronjob to execute the script